# How to get current page details in Mura CMS?

Tags: coldfusion, mura

For getting current page details:-

```
<cfdump var="#m.content().getAllValues()#">
```

> Reference : - [Mura content](http://docs.getmura.com/v7/theme-developers/creating-layout-templates/template-variables-helper-methods/content/)

Comment: Please redo this post.  [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Thank you Miguel. I tried to change question type as'Answer your own question', I think it is possible only when ask the question. I will follow from next time.